# How to set the NSView.backgroundColor within IB?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I know that it needs to have layers turned on and I know that it can be done programmatically BUT I need to do this frequently in test code so it would be nice to have an easy place to set it from within IB directly.

I notice that the animation inspector has a plethora of options relating to color and filters BUT none seem to relate to the actual color itself.

Comment: I had a related thought... instead of subViews, just add `box` controls because they seem to allow you to choose their color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**'*I need to do this frequently in test code*'**

If you're coloring the background of your views principally as a way of assisting you with the early stages of layout, one non-layers option - which avoids setting `backgroundColor` altogether -  is to make use of the *Runtime Attributes* table.

First, create your own super-simple view-class with a `backgroundFill` property:

```
@interface PPView ()

@property (nonatomic) NSColor *backgroundFill;

@end

@implementation PPView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    if (self.backgroundFill) {
        [self.backgroundFill setFill];
        [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds] fill];
    }
}

@end
```

Then, in Interface Builder, change the class of the relevant views to your new view subclass, and edit the *Runtime Attributes* table:

When you run your app, the views will be filled with the designated color:

[image]

The advantage of this approach over simply coloring the background using layers is that you can add other useful stuff to this subclass. A more advanced implementation of `PPView` would allow you to use *Runtime Attributes* to specify a string to be drawn across the centre of the view, and perhaps allow you to request a border:

[image]

Finally, if this *is* why you're after a way to change the background color, you should look into 'Live Views'. This aspect of Xcode lets you do all of the above in Interface Builder, and the result is also rendered live in Interface Builder - so no need to continually launch your app.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. I was hoping for a more built-in way but you have answered the question. Interestingly, I came across "Spot Colors" in the plethora of animation options - this appears to let you choose a color for a layer-backed view.